# Полоса прокрутки в QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qt5

Делаю такой виджет:

[image]

Все нормально, но при изменении размера скроллбар занимает два положения либо крайне левое, либо крайне правое:

[image]
[image]

То есть при данном размере во втором столбце игнорятся все данные с 3 по 13 отметку линейки.

Вопрос: как это исправить? Ведь `QTableWidget` скроллы наследует у `QAbstractScrollArea`, откуда они попадают в тот же `QGraphicsView` где прокрутка плавная, а не дискретная, я не понимаю как так.

qt 5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию в item view прокрутка не плавная, а дискретная по строкам и столбцам. Включить плавную прокрутку можно через `QAbstractItemView::setHorizontalScrollMode`:

```
table->setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
```